# GNU datamash transpose example doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: gnu

I am trying to replicate the example of using teh GNU datamash utility to transpose a file. I get a different output though. Not sure what's happening.

Instructions: https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/examples/#example_transpose

My output:

```
> ~/bin/Installed/datamash transpose < input.txt
Sample   Year   Count   id-123   2014   1002    id-99    2013    990    id-42    2014   2030    id-13    2014    599
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same output as you if I copy & paste `input.txt` from the example. If I replace multiple spaces with one tab it works as tab is the default separator.

```
$ datamash transpose < <(cat input.txt | tr -s ' ' '\t')
Sample  id-123  id-99   id-42   id-13
Year    2014    2013    2014    2014
Count   1002    990     2030    599
```

Or squeeze multiple spaces to one space and use option `-t' '` as field separator:

```
$ datamash -t' ' transpose < <(cat input.txt | tr -s ' ')
Sample id-123 id-99 id-42 id-13
Year 2014 2013 2014 2014
Count 1002 990 2030 599
```

Or even better, use option `-W` or `--whitespace` as pointed out by [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) (thanks!):

```
$ datamash -W transpose < input.txt
Sample  id-123  id-99   id-42   id-13
Year    2014    2013    2014    2014
Count   1002    990     2030    599
```

Comment: or you could simply add the `-W` (or `--whitespace`) option

Comment: Oh, didn't see that option. Very good point!

Comment: Thank you folks! I am good now.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure if `-W` was always an option - or added recently